# Opened vials must not be used in other patients - or "for other patients"

Tags: prepositions, terminology

From a package insert (solution for injections)

> Previously opened vials must not be used **in** other patients.

Is it okay? Or should it be

> Previously opened vials must not be used **for** other patients.

Comment: ...in the treatment of other patients.   *In other patients* is probably a (somewhat sloppy) shorthand for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect *with* to be most common here.

*In, on,* or *for* would also be idiomatic. They would be standard alternatives, but probably not the first choice.

Comment: Edited to include *on* as a possible choice as suggested in @probablyme's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the purpose of *these* vials are to be used for injections, then these vials would not be used inside of a person. So you wouldn't use *on*.

If you were to speak of other vials, and those vials were to be used used inside of a person, like inside of their mouth, ear, or other orifice, then *in* is ok.

Using *for* seems fine. It sounds like you are doing it on behalf of the patient though.

I would recommend *on* other patients, if the vial is being used physically upon the patients. Or *with* other patients, if the vial is being used near the patient or with samples from the patient in order to prevent contamination.

Comment: The context is a solution to be injected into patients. The fluid inside the vial would (at least ordinarily) be drawn into a syringe, and then injected "inside" a person. However, we would not say that the "vial" is used "in" a person. 

*On,* however, is a good choice, and probably more commonly used in this situation than for.

Comment: Yeah, when I wrote my answer I forgot about the first line. I noticed afterwards, but I didn't change my answer since I was clear that it was hypothetical. It should be clear to OP that the vials he was referring to were not being used inside a person regardless.

Comment: I still think that the choice of *in* is relatively unlikely. Consider: Don't use this medicine in children. I think it's not standard usage.

Comment: I realized that it's ordinary to say *use/not use (drug/medication) in / not use in patients.* You're right. And as you initially said, I believe *on* is also ok. So the main difference remaining is *with.* O.O

Answer (score 1):

The first example seems... icky. It's literally correct - for at least the contents of the vials anyway - but it rips away the medical veil for the squeamish:

> "Hey yeah, that really *does* go inside us! Ewww..."

As the others have said, "for", "with" or "on" all maintain that veil.